# Laravel: Set string as name for model

Tags: php, laravel, model

I´m working with polymorphic in Laravel 5.2. I want to set for the name of model string. There si code:

```
switch ($passport->element_type) {
            case 'Window':      
                $windows = Window::find($passport->element_id);
                break;
            case 'Floor':    
                $floor = Floor::find($passport->element_id);                    
                break;
            case 'Wall':
                $wall = Wall::find($passport->element_id);
            default:
                break;
        }
    };
```

You can see that variable "$passport->element_type" gives me the name of my model. I don´t want to do it with switch-case. Is it possible to do something like:

> $passport->element_type::find($passport->element_id);

or how can I use the variable (element_type) as the name for model?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: https://adamwathan.me/2015/09/03/pushing-polymorphism-to-the-database/ Adam Wathan describes the solution to this well. I don't have time to make it into an answer so i'll just drop the link here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set proper Model [relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations):

```
class Passport extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the owning likeable models.
     */
    public function pasportable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class Window extends Model
{
    public function pasport()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('App\Pasport', 'pasportable');
    }
}

class Floor extends Model
{
    public function pasport()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('App\Floor', 'pasportable');
    }
}

class Wall extends Model
{
    public function pasport()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('App\Wall', 'pasportable');
    }
}
```

and next you can access to morph'ed object by:

```
$passport->element();
// or
```

Passport::find($id)->element();

and it should return Model of Floor, Wall or Window depending on element_type

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it?

If

```
$passport->element_type::find($passport->element_id);
```

doesn't work, I know that

```
$type = new $passport->element_type;
$type::find($passport->element_id);
```

will.

Comment: No it doesn´t work. dd($type) return me "Window". But dd($type::find($passport->element_id)) throws error .. Class 'Window' not found.

Comment: `Class 'Window' not found` -- it's trying to work but it's not finding your model.

Comment: Yes, but  dd(Window::find($passport->element_id)) works

Comment: don´t know why but already $type = new $passport->element_type; throws error Class "Window" not found. I think that problem is that it is looking for class 'Window' with apostrophes and it should only looking for class Window without apostrophes.

Comment: Try it with this: `$type= "Window";`, see if it still throws that error.

Comment: How about `$type = 'Window';`? (single quotes) I don't think this would make a difference but it's worth trying.

Comment: Try using call_user_func_array(array($model, $method), array($argument)); or maybe use App::make($model) instead of the 'new' keyword.

Comment: With App::make it returns window without apostrophes (that´s what I need), but still error Class Window not found. I have in controller use App\Window; so I think it should find this class, but it doesn´t :/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for help. Finally works, but I needed to add path:

```
$type = App::make('\\App\\'.$passport->element_type);
```